# OSX El Capitan split-screen (4-way)

Tags: macos, split-view

Any good ways to easily do a 4-way split screen on OSX? I love split-screen and would love to also have 4 (in four corners) in addition to 2 (left-right).

Answer (score 2):

On my El Capitan Mac, I use BetterSnapTool. It’s a very good program for managing multiple side-by-side windows.

I even used it to to create a custom resizing command so my windows will not extend into the Notifications Area.

Available on the Mac App Store. Also see the developer’s web site: https://www.folivora.ai/bettersnaptool

Answer (score 1):

Not natively. Split screen is only two windows. You can always have four windows open on your desktop and manually resize them to fit the corners.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for https://github.com/jigish/slate, you can write your own config and key bindings.

and you can find slate configs from [here](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=filename%3A.slate%20bind&type=Code&ref=searchresults) if you don't want to write you're own